# Different CPU usage on two machine with same java and machine configuration

Tags: java, jvm, cpu, java-7, cpu-usage

We are running Esper java application on two different machines. Machines have same CPU and RAM configurations. We have used same 1.7 version JDK and JRE on both machines. Also, java configurations settings are also same.

Problem is, we are getting high CPU usage on one machine and but another is taking normal CPU. We didn't understand why this difference in CPU usage on both machines.

Please guide, if we are missing something here or if we can do something to reduce CPU usage and find its root cause.
Also, is there any tool that can provide us the machine and java configuration comparison from different machines.

Comment: Have you thought about profiling the application to see why it's using so much CPU?

Comment: You can use jvisualvm for validating CPU usage of java application.

Comment: Why are you so certain it's the Java side of the house? What is the profile of CPU, Memory usage, etc of the rest of what is running on the platforms?